# Ubuntu 20.04 GPU Not Found

Tags: 20.04, gpu, gpu-driver

So I have been trying to get my nVidia GPU detected by Ubuntu 20.04 for quite some time now, and none of the suggestions I have found online have helped. My main problem is that I can't see any output when running the suggested commands. Here are the things I have tried:

1. The first suggestion appears to be to run `lspci -v | grep VGA` which when I run it in the Ubuntu terminal give no output.
2. `lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d"` was suggested as well, but no luck.
3. Another suggestion was to run `sudo lshw -C video`, again no output.
4. Also ran `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`, no output
5. And finally `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'`

Checking these appears to be the first step in the solution proposed by contributors online, but I can't even get this first step running. Does anyone have suggestions on how I could proceed?

**Edit**

Perhaps I should also specify that I am using a Windows subsystem for Linux. Here are the outputs:

1. No output
2. No output
3. `Linux DESKTOP-IQST6BS 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
4. `Graphics:  Message: No Device data found. Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 120x30 Message: No advanced graphics data found on this system.`
5. No output
6. `[    1.890709] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)`

**Edit 2**

So I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#abstract) as recommended, but I still cannot connect to the GPU. For example when I input `sudo prime-select nvidia` the output is simply `Error: no integrated GPU detected.`. Can anyone maybe point me to what went wrong here?

Comment: Do you see any results when you run `lspci` or `sudo lshw` without the filters? Is this a desktop machine or a notebook?

Comment: I am working on a desktop machine with Windows 10. ` lspci´ shows no outout, but `sudo lshw´ does. Would you like me to post a particular output?

Comment: Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux? That requires an entirely different approach to direct hardware access and management ...

Comment: Yes I am using a subsystem, I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Given that you have WSL2, you should get the corresponding drivers.
See [CUDA on WSL](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl).

For a guide on how to install, please refer to

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#abstract

### Related

1. https://ubuntu.com/blog/getting-started-with-cuda-on-ubuntu-on-wsl-2
2. https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-install-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-11-in-wsl2-88292cf4ab77
3. https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/hxro9i/help_how_to_get_nvidia_driver_work_on_wsl2/
4. https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/n8lkts/where_to_download_old_version_of_nvidia_wsl_driver/
5. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6323

---

It is very strange that the commands you posted do not even show your main graphics card.

### Possible causes

(Strange hardware issues may be the culprit).

1. GPU is disabled at the BIOS level. Check that. If you have double boot with Windows, that would be good for a comparison.
2. Removing and replacing the CMOS battery [may help](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-not-detected-ubuntu/108341/14).
3. [An HDMI cable](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-not-detected-ubuntu/108341/23) may also be the problem.

### Extra / useful info

Please post the output of:

1. `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-nvidia`
2. `dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver`
3. `uname -a`
4. `inxi -G` (you may have to install `inxi`)
5. `grep 10de /lib/udev/rules.d/*`
6. `dmesg | grep nvidia`
7. `dmesg | grep NV`

### Related

1. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2443222

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the outputs to my original post.

Comment: Thanks for you updated answer, I was just afraid that if my Ubuntu can't even find the GPU then installing all the software would not work either. I'd upvote, but I don't hav enough rep here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly have the nvidia-drivers,

Go to the ubuntu's software and update center and under the additional driver's tab, see if you've enabled the nvidia proprietry driver(make sure that the driver should be other than the server one). In my case I missed that and spent a lot of my time trying other stuff.

Also note that for CUDA>10.1, the required driver version should be >=418.39