# My Ubuntu's GUI doesn't show things properly. How can I fix it?

Tags: apt, gnome, gui

**What happened:**
I installed adb and putty by using: `$apt install adb` and `$sudo apt install Putty`. Then, I started Putty and then I found out the configuration GUI of Putty doesn't show anything. After reboot, my Ubuntu's GUI doesn't show things properly. All the GUI of Ubuntu are enclosed by black blocks ( [as the image shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUIkC.jpg)) Some GUIs even don't show any words. Also, my input method (Sogou input method) crushes when I switch to it.

**System environment(using `$uname -a`):**
Linux jim 5.15.0-69-generic #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:19 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**What I have tried to fix the problem (but not working):**

1. Uninstalling Putty (doesn't fix the problem)
2. Reinstalling Ubuntu Desktop by using following commands(doesn't fix the problem):

```
$sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
$sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

**Logs:**
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcEu2.png)

Logs from `cat /var/log/apt/history.log` when installing 2 things (adb and Putty) before the problem occur:

```
Start-Date: 2023-04-18  10:15:02
Commandline: apt install adb
Requested-By: jim (1000)
Install: android-libbase:amd64 (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2, automatic), android-liblog:amd64 (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2, automatic), android-libcutils:amd64 (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2, automatic), adb:amd64 (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2), android-sdk-platform-tools-common:amd64 (27.0.0+12, automatic), android-libcrypto-utils:amd64 (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2, automatic), android-libboringssl:amd64 (8.1.0+r23-2build1, automatic), android-libadb:amd64 (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2, automatic)
End-Date: 2023-04-18  10:15:11

Start-Date: 2023-04-18  10:36:01
Commandline: apt-get install putty
Requested-By: jim (1000)
Install: putty:amd64 (0.73-2), putty-tools:amd64 (0.73-2, automatic)
End-Date: 2023-04-18  10:36:08
```

Logs from `cat /var/log/apt/term.log` when installing 2 things(adb and Putty) before the problem occur:

```
Log started: 2023-04-18  10:15:02
Selecting previously unselected package android-liblog.
(Reading database ... 255993 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-android-liblog_1%3a8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking android-liblog (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package android-libbase.
Preparing to unpack .../1-android-libbase_1%3a8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking android-libbase (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package android-libboringssl.
Preparing to unpack .../2-android-libboringssl_8.1.0+r23-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking android-libboringssl (8.1.0+r23-2build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package android-libcrypto-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../3-android-libcrypto-utils_1%3a8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking android-libcrypto-utils (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package android-libcutils.
Preparing to unpack .../4-android-libcutils_1%3a8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking android-libcutils (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package android-libadb.
Preparing to unpack .../5-android-libadb_1%3a8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking android-libadb (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package adb.
Preparing to unpack .../6-adb_1%3a8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking adb (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package android-sdk-platform-tools-common.
Preparing to unpack .../7-android-sdk-platform-tools-common_27.0.0+12_all.deb ...
Unpacking android-sdk-platform-tools-common (27.0.0+12) ...
Setting up android-sdk-platform-tools-common (27.0.0+12) ...
Setting up android-liblog (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up android-libboringssl (8.1.0+r23-2build1) ...
Setting up android-libcrypto-utils (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up android-libbase (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up android-libcutils (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up android-libadb (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up adb (1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Log ended: 2023-04-18  10:15:11

Log started: 2023-04-18  10:36:01
Selecting previously unselected package putty-tools.
(Reading database ... 256048 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../putty-tools_0.73-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking putty-tools (0.73-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package putty.
Preparing to unpack .../putty_0.73-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking putty (0.73-2) ...
Setting up putty-tools (0.73-2) ...
Setting up putty (0.73-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Log ended: 2023-04-18  10:36:08
```

I would like to know what cause this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: How *specifically* did you install putty, and what *specifically* does "doesn't work" mean in your item 1? Do you get error messages? Does your computer catch on fire? No mind readers here.

Comment: This should be a comment but I don't have the rep. Try pasting the output of `cat /var/log/apt/history.log` and `cat /var/log/apt/term.log` so that we can see what went wrong when you installed `sudo apt-get install Putty`. FYI, you can use this website to share snippets of text so you don't have to take screenshots each time: https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @OrganicMarble sorry for the ambiguous description. I think installing putty isn't specific at all. Also, there is no any error message when I install/start putty. However, there are some error message when entering Ubuntu system (see 'Logs') My "doesn't work" means what I tried doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @ekatko1 Thank you for your suggestion. The question updated with the content of output of `cat /var/log/apt/history.log` and `cat /var/log/apt/term.log`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there is anything wrong with the installation of those packages. They should not affect the graphics.

I've had a similar issue in the past and turning off a "window compositing" setting and changing the theme solved it (this was using Xfce window manager).

Ultimatley, however, the issue was that the incorrect graphics driver was installed. You can find your graphics card using the command:

`lspci | grep VGA`

If you are using Nvidia, then, you can look to make sure you have the correct `nvidia-driver-xxx` pacakge installed to work with your card. You can find the driver `xxx` via this page: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Comment: There are two graphic cards in my computer. One of them is Nvidia GTX850M.  I installed the Nvidia's driver from the link. However, that doesn't fix the problem. After using the command `lspci | grep VGA`, I got this: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)` . Does it mean the system not recognizing the Nvidia's graphic card? Do I need to change some settings to fix it? thx

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the Nvidia card is not being detected. It's not the newest card, so it's possible that it's a hardware problem (i.e. your Nvidia card is fried, or somehow became unplugged?). To use the integrated graphics card, you can run `sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-*` to remove any nvidia drivers you have installed (assuming they were installed via APT) and also stop the kernel from using them.

Comment: Also, check this Q for a list of functions to run to detect the GPU https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341161/ubuntu-20-04-gpu-not-found

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. After reading the page, trying the commands they list, I found the Nvidia card is able to be detected. (using `lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d"`. The second output: `01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)` ) It seems the Nvidia card is OK, but it is not used for VGA. Do you think I should reinstall the intel's graphic card driver.

Comment: Alright, that is good! So according to the nvidia website, you can use the latest driver (531). However, before changing anything, I suggest you check what is currently installed using the `nvidia-settings` command. There should be "NVIDIA Driver Version:" field on the first page (System Information).

Comment: Also, I found this article about using hybrid graphics (i.e. multiple graphics cards) https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu It's a bit old, but might still be helpful

Comment: Hey @killed_by_bugs, did you end up solving this?

Comment: no, I thought I spent too much time on this problem. So I have reinstalled my Ubuntu to solve the problem. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.